# synchronized views on a Panel using AJAX

Tags: views, ajax, panels

Using drupal 7, I have two views (map and table), both with the same exposed filters, inside of a Panel.

Currently these views are View Panes, both with the parameter 'Use Panel Path': Yes, and AJAX: no

One of the view's filters is hidden to the user, so we simulate a single filter for both views.

When user filters the data, all parameters are sent via GET and both views are correctly updated, but it causes a refresh of all the page and we have a very long GET request.

So I want to use AJAX to synchronize both views. I have done some tests using AJAX 'yes' in both views, changing the Panel Path... but I think I am not on the right track.

thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think I understand the question. There seems to be an awful lot of text just to ask how to update a view via ajax. Is that all you want?

Comment: Update one of the views inside a Panel using the params used previously to create the other view without refreshing all the page, just the selected view. Thanks. Hope it makes clear...

Comment: Was that meant to add information to the question? If so, please edit the original question, don't use comments for that purpose.